# Python regex to find string which ends with A OR B, either if A comes first or B (non-greedy search)

Tags: python, regex

I have the following python code
    `data = re.sub("{.{4,9}b .*?[\r\n]*?.*? ((.*\\()|(..fs24))",string,re.DOTALL)`

I want to be able to have two matches for each of the strings below

```
?{\f1\fs24\b \u1510 ?}\u1489 ?\fs24
```

and

```
?{\f1\fs24\b \u1492 ?}\u1494 ?(
```

In both permutations of the both

```
?{\f1\fs24\b \u1492 ?}\u1494 ?(  ?{\f1\fs24\b \u1510 ?}\u1489 ?\fs24
?{\f1\fs24\b \u1510 ?}\u1489 ?\fs24 ?{\f1\fs24\b \u1492 ?}\u1494 ?(
```

However, the OR operator is greedy. So it will always try to feed the first operand and so in both cases it will consume the whole string and give me only one match...

It took me some time to understand the greediness...
To solve I was playing with positive lookahead assumptions. 
I was also trying to do two separate searches but the greediness always wins...

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly your text is, and what you expect your regex to match. Also, the regex you currently have has unbalanced parentheses, so won't work at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: parentheses are not unbalanced, look carefully, one of the parentheses is escaped.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: regex101 doesn't know that the pattern is not in a raw string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ah, non-raw regex strings FTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but if you want to stop at the first `(` or `..fs24`, then you need to use a negative lookahead to check each `.` match is being matched.

```
data = re.search(r"{.{4,9}b .*?[\r\n]*?.*? ((?:(?!\(| ..fs24).)*)", string, re.DOTALL)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you're matching, you'll need `re.search` (or `re.findall` for multiple matches in a whoop). You'll need two input strings anyway with `re.sub`.

Notes:

- Raw your regex strings to avoid having to double escape metacharacters.
- `.*?[\r\n]*?.*?`: this part doesn't quite seem useful to me, but I left it there since I don't know what you're trying to do besides stopping at the first `(` or `..fs24`.

[regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/yV5hA4/3) for the last string where you get 2 matches instead of 1.

Comment: Jerry - I am still trying to understand exactly what it does. However, I need to match fs24 only if it of form <space><anychar><anychar>fs24. In your regex it consumes even this form <nonspace><anychar><anychar>. Here is the link :http://regex101.com/r/yV5hA4/2

Comment: @LouisShraga Ah, I didn't know that was a requirement. That's why you need to e clear in your question. Just add a space before the two dots in `..fs24`.

Comment: Jerry The reason for the .*?[\r\n]*?.*? is that I want to be able to match accross multiple lines and re.DOTALL did not work.. With your addition the multiline search ability was lost... Can you hint me please or should I open a new question ?

Comment: @LouisShraga It should work just fine if you removed that part and keep re.DOTALL. I need to go now and dont't have time for another edit to my answer. Will be back in abt 8 hrs

Comment: Jerry I found the problem with re.DOTALL, I was using it positionally, when switched to flags=re.DOTALL it all got sorted out.Thanks !